# Iodized or sea salt

Tags: flavor, salt

In cooking, should I chose iodized or sea salt? I have no particular health or thyroid concerns, but I'm not particularly sure on what the difference of the flavor can either of the two bring.

Comment: Be aware; the fact that you aren't worried about iodine deficiency doesn't mean you won't have an iodine deficiency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some people can taste iodine in salt (not pleasant), and for some purposes (like brining), iodized salt is not recommended.

I use non-iodized table salt for some purposes, and kosher salt (which is non-iodized by definition) for others. Kosher salt is just salt with larger crystals than table salt.

There is no culinary reason to use iodized salt for anything.

Comment: -1 There is however, a health reason. If you don't taste the difference, use iodized salt.

Comment: There might be a health reason, but that is outside the scope of this stack. I don't mind being downvoted, but I do want to point out *why* I did not bring that up - I made a point to say that there is no *culinary* reason to use iodized salt.

Comment: @Jolenealaska there's no culinary reason not to use iodized salt. Naturally extracted marine salt has iodine, and some of them are considered gourmet products.